# Read char array row in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

### What I have

I've a char array, defined by doing an strcat between two char arrays like this:

```
coeficientes = strcat(coef_bin, coef_bin_comp)
```

Then, I want to read each row and convert them to hex. I'm doing it like:

```
for k=1:11

  coef_binario = coeficientes(1+(k-1)*8:k*8);

  coef_hexadecimal = binaryVectorToHex( coef_binario - '0' );

  fprintf('%s\t%s\n', coef_binario, coef_hexadecimal);

end
```

### What's the result

If I print both `coeficientes` variable and each `coef_binario` I take to convert, results are the following:

Note: `coeficientes` is printed by just removing semicolon after strcat line, but `coef_binario` is printed by using `fprintf` as is written above.

```
coeficientes =

00011111 00111101 01001100 01011011 01111001 10001000 10010111
10110101 11000100 11010011 11110001

00000111     07      11100111     E7      00011101     1D 
00100100     24      11101101     ED      10111111     BF     
11000001     C1      11000111     C7      00100100     24     
10010110     96      11011011     DB
```

### The Problem

As you can see, I've tried to read the `coeficientes` var row by row using:

```
coef_binario = coeficientes(1+(k-1)*8:k*8);
```

But when it's printed, binary code doesn't match with the original one. Any idea about why or how can I do it in order to have it correctly?

***Update 1***

If I try to split it before doing it, in order to use `strsplit` before I need to get the string. I've tried:

```
strs = strsplit(sprintf('%s', coeficientes), ' ')
```

From this, I obtain again the *wrong* chain. In fact, after using just `sprintf` (and not `strsplit`), what I get is:

> 0000011111100111000111010010010011101101101111111100000111000111001001001001011011011011

***Update 2***

How `coeficientes` is generated:

```
% coef_k is a vector of decimal numbers, i.e.: [1 3 5 8 11 14]
coef_bin = dec2bin(coef_k);
coef_complementario = 16 - coef_k;

coef_bin_comp = dec2bin(coef_complementario);

coeficientes = strcat(coef_bin, coef_bin_comp)
```

Comment: It is not clear what `coeficientes` is. Is it a string? A cell array of strings? Can you add an actual Matlab statement that would produce `coeficientes` that we can use.

Comment: Added @nirvana-msu. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate issue is that MATLAB stores data in column-major order so essentially what is happening is that if your data is a 2D character array (the output of `dec2bin`):

```
c = ['00011111'
     '00111101'
     '01001100'
     '01011011'
     '01111001'
     '10001000'
     '10010111'
     '10110101'
     '11000100'
     '11010011'
     '11110001'];
```

Then when you use a linear index like `1+(k-1)*8:k*8`, it reads *down the columns* rather than across the rows like you want.

For example for `k = 1`:

```
k = 1;
c(1+(k-1)*8:k*8)
% 00000111  <---- Clearly not the first row. It is the first 8 entries going
%                 down the first column.
```

You have four options:

1. Transpose `c` prior to your processing (to make the numbers go down the columns instead):

   ```
   c = c.';

   k = 1;
   c(1+(k-1)*8:k*8)
   % 00011111 <---- The first row like you would expect!
   ```
2. Adjust your index expression to go across the columns instead

   ```
   k = 1;
   c(k:size(c,1):end)
   % 00011111 <---- The first row like you would expect!
   ```
3. Just use normal matrix indexing to grab a row

   ```
   k = 1;
   c(k,:)
   % 00011111 <---- The first row like you would expect!
   ```
4. Just use the built-in `bin2dec` followed by `dec2hex` to get the hexadecimal representation. If you pass a 2D character array to `bin2dec` it interprets each *row* as a different binary number.

   ```
   hex = dec2hex(bin2dec(c));

       1F
       3D
       4C
       5B
       79
       88
       97
       B5
       C4
       D3
       F1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strsplit` to split your input string using space as a delimiter (available in R2013a+, otherwise use e.g. `regexp`). You can also replace `for` loop with `cellfun` to make it more compact:

```
coeff = '00011111 00111101 01001100 01011011 01111001 10001000 10010111 10110101 11000100 11010011 11110001';

strs = strsplit(coeff, ' ');
hex = cellfun(@(str) binaryVectorToHex(str-'0'), strs, 'uni', false);

>> hex
hex = 
    '1F'    '3D'    '4C'    '5B'    '79'    '88'    '97'    'B5'    'C4'    'D3'    'F1'
```

**UPDATE**

With your input (char matrix) you don't even need `strsplit`. Just use a combination of `bin2dec` and `dec2hex` as proposed by @Suever. You may also want to wrap resulting hex values into individual cells using `cellstr`.

```
cellstr(dec2hex(bin2dec(coeficientes)))
```

Comment: I've tried, and to not get an error (since for me, `coeff` is what `strcat` returns), I had to use `sprintf` to have the string in order to use it into strsplit. Then, I've found that after using `sprintf`, I obtain again the "wrong" chain, just as is shown in my example above =S. I'll update the post with it better explained.

Comment: The problem was like Suever pointed, but thanks for the cellfun idea, quite nice! Upvote!